# How do I make a button event with innerhtml in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, innerhtml

I tried a lot off things but the innerhtml just doesn't go to the onclick function. I use mysql database and put the innerhtml in a datareader which all work perfectly. The only problem is that i can't click on the html buttons and the asp:buttons arent showing up (also tried linkbuttons, onserverclick etc). I need the onclick function and not javascript because the sql doesn't work in javascript. Can anyone help me?

I tried to use it like this:

```
while(dr.read())
{
    ...
    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += "<td style='float:right'><button runat='server' onserverclick='btnTrash_Click'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button></td>";
```

and tried:

```
    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += "<td style='float:right'><asp:LinkButton style='height:50px;width:50px' id='btnTrash' onClick='btnTrash_Click'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></asp:LinkButton></td>";
}
```

onclick thingy (I normally check this in debug mode):

```
protected void btnTrash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('test')</script>");
        }
```

html:

```
    <tbody>
                            <div id="WinkelmandBody" runat="server">
                            </div>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Sub-Totaal</td>
                                <td class="text-right" runat="server" id="SubTotaal"></td>                      
</tr>   
    </tbody>
```

These all worked, it's only the button that doesn't:

```
WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += "<tr>";
                    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += $"<td><img src='imgs/{dr[2]}' style='height: 50px; width: 50px; '/> </td>";
                    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += $"<td>{dr[1]}</td>";
                    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += $"<td>{stock}</td>";
                    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += $"<td style='text-align:center; border:none'><input style='text-align:center' type='text' value='{dr[0]}' /></td>";
                    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += $"<td style='text-align:right'>{ Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]) * (Convert.ToInt32(dr[0])) }€</td>";
```

Comment: How does it render it in the webpage (html tags)? Can you show us with the html inspector? Where is the 'btnTrash_Click' function located?

Comment: I edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little sidenote. A month after this post I didn't use innerhtml for showing my products but I used an asp:datalist. For the shopping basket I used asp:literal which worked way better than the innerhtml. This allowed me to use bootstrap 4 which I could use with the innerhtml control.

If you have anymore questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create "server-side markup" at runtime in ASP.NET WebForms. Instead of setting `InnerHtml` or emitting markup script, you should add controls programmatically:

aspx file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="WinkelmandBody" runat="server">
    </div>
</form>
```

cs file:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var table = new Table();
    var headerRow = new TableHeaderRow();
    table.Rows.Add(headerRow);
    // other code for header row ...

    var row = new TableRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    var cell = new TableCell();
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    cell.Style["float"] = "right";
    Button btnTrash = new Button();
    btnTrash.Text = "Trash";
    btnTrash.Click += BtnTrash_Click;

    WinkelmandBody.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

Also, instead of `Response.Write`, use [`RegisterStartupScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript):

```
private void BtnTrash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = "alert('test');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
}
```

## Why your code didn't work

When you add `runat="server"` to a tag in an aspx file, ASP.NET creates a corresponding object for the tag, **while loading the page for the first time**. `runat="server"` is not processed while rendering the page. It is processed while parsing the "aspx" or "ascx" file. So you cannot add server-side controls in the markup text programmatically.

Comment: I find it weird that all my other innerhtml works except the button. There is not problem with the table.

Comment: @MelihÖzcan They work because they are just HTML markups, not ASP.NET markup with `runat="server"` and `Click` event handler!.

Comment: I know that your table works fine, but there is no way to add controls to the table if it is just rendered in HTML and doesn't have a C# object in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript instead. For example:

Add the following hidden input field at the page within the "Form" element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
<input type="hidden" name="itemid" id="itemid" />
```

Add the following script at the header of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doPostBack(action, itemid) {
        document.getElementById('action').value = action;
        document.getElementById('itemid').value = itemid;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Here, continue with your code:

```
WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += "<td style='float:right'><a href='# onclick=\"doPostBack('remove','1'); return false;\"><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></td>";
```

At the page load event, capture the action value:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string action = Request.Form["action"] + "";
        string itemid = Request.Form["itemid"] + "";

        if (action == "remove")
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

In above presented code, this part is hard coded. This is because I'm presenting the idea.

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"doPostBack('remove','1'); return false;\">
```

You can of course change it dynamically according to your situation, for example:

```
while(dr.read())
{
    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += "<a href='#' onclick=\"doPostBack('remove',";
    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += dr[0] + "";
    WinkelmandBody.InnerHtml += "); return false;\">";
}
```

Comment: I hard coded the value, this is because I'm presenting the idea and that's the example. It doesn't mean you can't un-hardcoded it, right? You can code it dynamically right? and change the value dyncamically in your coding.

Comment: I have added some example of how to "not hard coded it".

Comment: Could you look at my newer post. I get what you are doing but it's not what I need. I'm just not good at explaining

Comment: @MelihÖzcan which means, in condition A, the row has 1 button, and in condition B, the row has has 2 buttons. Is this right?